# JavaScript: Remove value from URL search parameter

Tags: javascript

I've this URL here:

```
http://localhost.com/?color=Red,Blue,Green
```

The URL can also have this format:

```
http://localhost.com/?color=Red,Green,Blue
```

I'm trying now to remove the value `Green` from the URL including the `,` if it acts as separator. I've tried this RegExp here:

```
var name = 'Green';
var re = new RegExp('(' + name + ',|' + name + ')');
var newUrl = window.location.search.replace(re, '');
window.history.pushState(null, null, newUrl);
```

So what I want to say is, remove `Green,` or `Green` so if the `Green,` can't be found, the second check will be used. But when I run this the URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost.com/?olor=Red,Green,Blue
```

It removed the `c` from the color which is totally strange. I've tested my `RegExp` online in an tool and the texts were selected but here it don't works. What I'm doing wrong again?

**Update**

This is a try with Brunos answer but as you can see sometimes it don't woks:

```js
function replaceColor(search, name) {
  var reS = new RegExp(`=${name}(,|$)`);
  var reM = new RegExp(`,${name},`);
  var reE = new RegExp(`\b${name}$`);
  return search
    .replace(reS, '=')
    .replace(reM, ',')
    .replace(reE, '')
    .replace(/,$/, '')
}

alert(replaceColor('?size=K,M,S&color=Green,Red,Black', 'Red')) //Works

alert(replaceColor('?size=K,M,S&color=Green,Red,Black', 'Green')) //Works

alert(replaceColor('?size=K,M,S&color=Green,Red,Black', 'Black')) //Don't works
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally made it:

```
var reA = new RegExp('Value you want to remove');
var reB = new RegExp('(,&)');
var reC = new RegExp('(,,)');
var reD = new RegExp('(=,)');
var reE = new RegExp('(,$)');
window.history.pushState(null, null, decodeURIComponent(window.location.search).replace(reA, '').replace(reB, '&').replace(reC, ',').replace(reD, '=').replace(reE, ''));
```

Just enter the value you want to remove or pass a variable here with the value. Should work. For me it does.

Answer (score 5):

**Why your example doesn't work:**

Your regex looks for `green` or `green,`, however in your first example, the URL contains `,green`. Being that you only replace the `green` portion of it, the result is a trailing comma: `red,blue,`.

> It removed the `c` from the color which is totally strange.

I see nothing in your example that would demonstrate this behavior. I'd assume this is unrelated to the code you've provided.

```js
var name = 'Green';
var re = new RegExp('(' + name + ',|' + name + ')');
var newUrl = "http://localhost.com/?color=Red,Blue,Green".replace(re, '');
console.log(newUrl);
```

---

As it seems [Bruno has already covered the Regex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53679258/2026606), I'll leave you with a few alternatives.

**Using [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)**

You could fetch the param using `URLSearchParams`,  [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the values into an array, [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out `green`, and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them back together.

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const colors = urlParams.get('color');

let result = colors.split(",").filter(n => n != "green").join(",");
```

**If you need to support Internet Explorer**, you can reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/2026606) that includes the following method to retrieve the URL parameters - the `result` portion can remain the same:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  if (!url) url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
  var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

var colors = gerParameterByName("color"); 
var result = colors.split(",").filter(n => n != "green").join(",");
```

Comment: Correct. I can edit to include an IE-friendly solution.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @melpomene Edited

Comment: The question was why "*It removed the `c` from the color*".

Comment: The "why" in your comment is your own addition, and changes the context of OP's actual question. While OP mentioned that the removal of the `c` was strange behavior, their question was *"What I'm doing wrong again?"*. I explained what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing your code slightly would do it, but you should probably use Tyler's strategy to manipulate as an array instead

```
function replaceColor(search, name) {
  var reS = new RegExp(`=${name}(,|$)`);
  var reM = new RegExp(`,${name},`);
  var reE = new RegExp(`[=,]${name}$`);
  return search
    .replace(reS, '=')
    .replace(reM, ',')
    .replace(reE, '')
    .replace(/,$/, '')
}

var name = 'Green';
var newUrl = replaceColor(window.location.search, name);
window.history.pushState(null, null, newUrl);
```

Example:

```js
function replaceColor(search, name) {
  var reS = new RegExp(`=${name}(,|$)`);
  var reM = new RegExp(`,${name},`);
  var reE = new RegExp(`[=,]${name}$`);
  return search
    .replace(reS, '=')
    .replace(reM, ',')
    .replace(reE, '')
    .replace(/,$/, '')
}

console.log(replaceColor('?color=Red,Green,Blue', 'Red'))
console.log(replaceColor('?color=Red,Green,Blue', 'Green'))
console.log(replaceColor('?color=Red,Green,Blue', 'Blue'))

console.log(replaceColor('?color=Red,DarkGreen,Blue', 'Green'))
console.log(replaceColor('?color=DarkGreen', 'Green'))
console.log(replaceColor('?color=Green', 'Green'))
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with ä, ü, ö, ß in german language. So for example when you set the first parameter to `groß` it's not working

Comment: @Mr.Jo I could not reproduce what you mentioned. There's nothing in this code that would cause an issue with any language (as long as they all use the same character `,` to separate words). Maybe try to isolate the issue and post a new question.

Comment: Hey, I've updated my question so you can see the issue. When I run your answer this thing don't works on my browser side: console.log(replaceColor('?color=Red,Green,Blue', 'Blue'))

Comment: Sir are you still there?

Answer (score -1):

Add more condition into your regex

```
var re = new RegExp('(' + name + ',|' + name + '|,' + name + ')');
```